# Qt - MainWindow freezes when running

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get large data from a database but when running the main window freezes.

I am working under windows and according to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows automatically set the program to a hanging state state after 5 seconds.

Is there a way to prevent freezing?

Here is the code:

```
void MainWindow::on_getDataButtonClicked()
{
    ui->centralWidget->setEnabled(false);
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
    try
    {
        Client client(user, password);

        std::future<map<string, map<string, string> > > fut =
                  std::async(std::launch::async, &Client::get_data, &client);

        // While not all data has been retrieved, set message to the status bar.
        while (fut.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) != std::future_status::ready)
        {
            ui->statusBar->showMessage("Getting data.");
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            ui->statusBar->showMessage("Getting data..");
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            ui->statusBar->showMessage("Getting data...");
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }

        map<string, map<string, string> > exported_strings = std::move(fut.get());

        ui->statusBar->showMessage("%All data has been retrieved!");
    }
    catch (std::string& s)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", QString::fromStdString(s));
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", QString(e.what()));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "An unknown error has occurred.");
    }
    ui->centralWidget->setEnabled(true);
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
}
```

On a side note, the main window does not freezes when debugging.

Comment: You might want to check out `QProgressDialog`. It basically does exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To avoid multithreading, here's what you should do:

- Cut your code (virtually, just in thought) into chunks
- Run your program and study these chunks, and see which of them causes the freezing (takes longest to execute)
- Once you know what part causes the freezing, use `QApplication::processEvents();` to force the `MainWindow` to become responsive.

**Example**: Let me illustrate with an example. Say you have this function

```
void MainWindow::on_getDataButtonClicked()
{
    //do some easy stuff
    for(long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        //do some stuff
        //do some other stuff
    }
    //do some different stuff
}
```

Now while executing this nasty function, your window will definitely freeze until the whole function is finished. The "easy stuff" is not the problem, because it's fast. But the big loop is the problem. So all you have to do is tell Qt to reprocess the events that get the main window to become responsive again; Like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_getDataButtonClicked()
{
    //do some easy stuff
    for(long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        QApplication::processEvents();
        //do some stuff
        //do some other stuff
    }
    QApplication::processEvents();
    //do some different stuff
}
```

How many times should you call `processEvents();`? Call it whenever you want the window to respond again. If in doubt, just put `processEvents()` like everywhere! Infest every line with that. It's not the best practice, but then you can remove them one by one and see where your program starts freezing again.

One additional piece of advice: Don't throw `std::string` exceptions. This is a very bad idea. Learn how to throw classes inherited from `std::exception`. You can still hold your string inside the `std::exception` object. For example, you can do: `throw std::exception("This is very very bad");`. There are many other classes you can throw. Find them [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

Comment: `QApplication::processEvents()` Solved the issue. Thanks! Also, thanks for the comment about the std::string exception. I forgot to update this part.

Comment: Except that this is horrible advice. In most cases reentering the event loop, like `QApplication::processEvents` does, causes reentrancy-related bugs. **Event worse, this is a horrible energy hog since you busy-wait!** Do *not* heed this advice!

Comment: @KubaOber It depends very much on the complexity of the program and what you want to achieve. Using `processEvents()` is one of the possible solutions provided in the Qt official website. If it's totally bad as you mention, they would've said that. Check here: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html

Comment: While this hack *may* seem like it's a solution - it really is not.. please don't go down this path. If you need to call `processEvents` explicitly then you know you are in trouble.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is the ONLY possible solution without multithreading. I understand your contention, guys, but this is a simple solution that can be misused. Better tell the asker how to avoid misusing it than telling it to run away from it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You do understand that `std::async` is already multithreading? The whole point of using it is so that the GUI thread won't be blocked! The pesky `while` loop is the only thing that wrecks it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Take manuals with a grain of salt. As Feynman said: "reality must take precedence over public relations, for nature cannot be fooled." Here, code speaks for itself. Even if the manual doesn't enumerate all possible problems, it doesn't mean they aren't there. Qt is an open-source project and the documentation, while mostly excellent, has plenty of dirty corners and rough edges.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist "It depends very much on the complexity of the program and what you want to achieve" Here, the complexity of the program is nil: you're doing busy-waiting on a flag set in another thread. This is a classical, energy-wasting spin-wait. If you want to get intense hatred from your users, go right ahead and do just that.

Answer (score 3):

There's no point to doing asynchronous work if you're waiting for it and blocking the GUI thread anyway in the `while` loop. You need to get rid of the `while` loop.

You could use `QtConcurrent::run` instead of `std::async`, and use `QFutureWatcher` to get notified asynchronously, without blocking, when the async task has finished.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/async-sane-39396761
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Client {
    using result_type = std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>;
    result_type get_data() {
        QThread::sleep(5); // pretend to do some work
        return result_type();
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    Client::result_type exported_strings;
    QWidget centralWidget;
    QVBoxLayout layout{&centralWidget};
    QPushButton getDataButton{"Get Data"};
    QStatusBar statusBar;
    QTimer statusTimer;
    QString statusMessage;

    void setBusyStatus(const QString & status) {
        centralWidget.setEnabled(false);
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
        statusMessage = status;
        statusTimer.start(0);
    }
    void setNormalStatus(const QString & status) {
        centralWidget.setEnabled(true);
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        statusBar.showMessage(status);
        statusTimer.stop();
    }
    Q_SLOT void on_getDataButtonClicked();
public:
    MainWindow() {
        setStatusBar(&statusBar);
        setCentralWidget(&centralWidget);
        layout.addWidget(&getDataButton);
        int n = 0;
        connect(&statusTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() mutable {
            statusBar.showMessage(QStringLiteral("%1%2").arg(statusMessage).arg(QString{n+1, QChar{'.'}}));
            n = (n+1)%3;
            statusTimer.start(500);
        });
        connect(&getDataButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::on_getDataButtonClicked);
    }
};

void MainWindow::on_getDataButtonClicked()
{
    auto future = QtConcurrent::run([=]{
        Client client;
        return client.get_data();
    });
    auto watcher = new QFutureWatcher<Client::result_type>{this};
    connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<Client::result_type>::finished, this, [=]{
        exported_strings = std::move(watcher->result());
        watcher->deleteLater();
        setNormalStatus("All data has been retrieved!");
    });
    watcher->setFuture(future);
    setBusyStatus("Getting data");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Alternatively, you could emit a signal from the async code, letting you retain the use of `std::async` if you prefer that:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <future>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Client {
    using result_type = std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>;
    result_type get_data() {
        QThread::sleep(5); // pretend to do some work
        return result_type();
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    Client::result_type exported_strings;
    QWidget centralWidget;
    QVBoxLayout layout{&centralWidget};
    QPushButton getDataButton{"Get Data"};
    QStatusBar statusBar;
    QTimer statusTimer;
    QString statusMessage;

    std::future<Client::result_type> resultFuture;

    void setBusyStatus(const QString & status) {
        centralWidget.setEnabled(false);
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
        statusMessage = status;
        statusTimer.start(0);
    }
    void setNormalStatus(const QString & status) {
        centralWidget.setEnabled(true);
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        statusBar.showMessage(status);
        statusTimer.stop();
    }
    Q_SLOT void on_getDataButtonClicked();
    Q_SIGNAL void hasResult();
public:
    MainWindow() {
        setStatusBar(&statusBar);
        setCentralWidget(&centralWidget);
        layout.addWidget(&getDataButton);
        int n = 0;
        connect(&statusTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() mutable {
            statusBar.showMessage(QStringLiteral("%1%2").arg(statusMessage).arg(QString{n+1, QChar{'.'}}));
            n = (n+1)%3;
            statusTimer.start(500);
        });
        connect(&getDataButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::on_getDataButtonClicked);
    }
};

void MainWindow::on_getDataButtonClicked()
{
    connect(this, &MainWindow::hasResult, this, [this](){
        exported_strings = std::move(resultFuture.get());
        setNormalStatus("All data has been retrieved!");
    }, Qt::UniqueConnection);

    resultFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]{
        Client client;
        auto result = client.get_data();
        emit hasResult();
        return result;
    });
    setBusyStatus("Getting data");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything is happening on the same thread and some operation is slow, then you won't get back to the event-loop in time for the OS to not declare you as stuck.

The solution(s) are to either;

1) use multiple processes.

2) use multiple threads.

3) divide the work on your one thread into chunks that are all guaranteed to be small enough that you can get back to servicing the eventloop in a timely fashion.